# Regex, find timezone Except UTC timezone when both are available

Tags: regex

I went through many questions on this website but didn't find the solution yet.

I am working on an automation engine which has to read emails automatically. These emails contain both UTC and local time in the message body and I have to pick only non-UTC time for processing it further.

Below is the sample content of the email body. Regex I have tried, is returning both the timezones:

**String (Message body)**:

```
Date/ Time 1 (SGT): 05-Jan-2020 01:00 - 05-Jan-2020 05:00

Date/ Time 1 (UTC): 04-Jan-2020 17:00 - 04-Jan-2020 21:00
```

**Regex**:

```
Date\s{0,}\/\s{0,}Time.*\((?<TimeZone>\w{3})\)\s{0,}:\s{0,}(?<StartDate>\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}\s{1,}\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s{0,}-\s{0,}(?<EndDate>\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}\s{1,}\d{1,2}:\d{2})
```

How to pick only the times from the line which has non-UTC time.

Comment: You could add a negative lookahead for `UTC` in the `TimeZone` group: https://regex101.com/r/91gUZ8/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following regex pattern:

```
^Date/ Time \d+ \((?!UTC\b).*?\): .*$
```

### Demo

Not much to explain here, except that term: `\((?!UTC\b).*?\):`

This will match any timezone in parentheses except for UTC.

Comment: Though this is not the exact thing that I was trying to do. Your answer helped me to find the right solution: `Date\s{0,}\/\s{0,}Time.*\((?<TimeZone>(?!\bUTC\b).*)\)\s{0,}:\s{0,}(?<StartDate>\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}\s{1,}\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s{0,}-\s{0,}(?<EndDate>\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}\s{1,}\d{1,2}:\d{2})`

Comment: @SavindraSingh I left out the capture groups for the various date and time components, but I assumed you would know how to add those as you wanted.